# Unable to connect StormCrawler to secured Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I am getting the below error

> noNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{buKSP622TFWnQm_2-PxqQg}{xxxxxxxx}{10.240.49.79:2309}]] at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.

When trying to connect to a secured elasticsearch cluster.

The setup works with non-xpack enabled elasticsearch. How do I connect storm crawler to secured elasticsearch?

Comment: Did you check the ``es.nodes.wan.only`` parameter?

Comment: I have same problem. With com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler (storm-crawler-elasticsearch) version 1.6 was ok, when upgrade to version 1.7 I see this error.

Comment: @IvanBukharin please see my answer below and try the new branch. If that doesn't work please open an issue on github. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is going to work, depending on the version etc... but first, you need to add the shield jar to the classpath as explained in [java client with shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/_using_elasticsearch_java_clients_with_shield.html). This is easily done with Maven

```
 <repositories>
  <!-- add the elasticsearch repo -->
  <repository>
     <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
     <url>https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases</url>
     <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
  </repository>
```

[...]

```
      <dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
     <artifactId>shield</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Everything else can be done via the configuration, for the *status* index

es.status.plugins: org.elasticsearch.shield.ShieldPlugin
  es.status.settings:
    cluster.name: "ENTER_CLUSTER_NAME"
    shield.user": "transport_client_user:changeme"

The [TransportExample.java](https://github.com/elastic/found-shield-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cloud/transport/example/TransportExample.java) might be a good example and list all the settings required.

Please note that Elastic Cloud currently doesn't work with the TransportClient in versions 6.1.x and above which is what the master branch of StormCrawler is on. You could downgrade to an older version of the ES module for SC and refer to the corresponding documentation.

Another option would be to port the code to use the high-level rest client, see [migration guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.2/java-rest-high-level-migration.html) but that's quite a task.

**UPDATE**: Please look at the branch [ESRestAPi](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/ESRestAPi). I've changed the code so that it uses the ES REST client. This works with Elastic Cloud 6.2 and all you need to do is specify

```
  es.status.user: "USERNAME"
  es.status.password: "PASSWORD"
```

to the config for each index. The addresses now take normal URLs with the protocol, hostname and port.

Please let me know if you got it to work.